# Timer0 overflow interrupt does not work on ATtiny10

Tags: avr, interrupts, attiny

I am trying to use the Timer0 overflow interrupt to make a little project.
I used such a timer in the ATtiny45 and it worked, but with ATtiny10 no result.

So I tried an easy LED blinking program and even that didn't work.

Here is the simple code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL  // 1 MHz

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

volatile uint16_t overflow_val=0;

ISR (TIMER0_OVF_vect){
  overflow_val++;
}

int main(void){
  DDRB = (1<<PB1);
  // Timer0 normal mode
  TCCR0A = 0x00;
  // Start timer with presc 1:1024
  TCCR0B = (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);
  TCNT0 = 0;
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0);
  sei();

  for(;;){  
    if(overflow_val >= 1)
        {
            if(TCNT0 >= 145){
                PORTB ^= (1 << PB1);
                TCNT0 = 0;
                overflow_val = 0;
            }
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

**EDIT1:**

I changed line

```
TCCR0B = (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);
```

to line

```
TCCR0B = (1 << CS01);  // clk/8
```

in my code to achieve an overflow every 0.524sec. But the LED is not blinking at all.

**EDIT2:**

Here is the size:

```
>avr-size test_attiny10_2.ino.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    138       0       2     140      8c test_attiny10_2.ino.elf
```

**EDIT3:**

I changed my if statement in the main as follows:

```
int main(void){

  ...

  TCCR0B = (1 << CS01);

  ...

  for(;;){
    if(TCNT0 >= 0xFFFE)
        {
                PORTB ^= (1 << PB1);
                TCNT0 = 0;
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now my LED is flashing all 0.524 seconds as it should!

So something is wrong with my volatile unit16_t variable **overflow_val**.
Not only i tested it directly on hardware, but did also a simulation with atmelstudio. Also in the simulation the program is never entering the if statement if i use the variable **overflow_val** to toggle the LED.

**EDIT 4**

I think something is not right with my ISR fkt. I testet the following code and i never got the LED switched on.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL  // 1 MHz

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

volatile uint8_t ovf_counter = 0;

void ioinit(void){
    // PB1->outputs
    DDRB = (1<<PB1);

    // Start timer with presc 1:64
    TCCR0B = (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00);
    // Initialize counter Overflow at 0xFFFF
    TCNT0 = 0;

    // Enable global interrupts
    sei(); 
}

int main(void){
    ioinit();
    TIMSK0 |= (1<<TOIE0);
      while(1){        
        if(ovf_counter>=2){
          PORTB = (1<<PB1);
          ovf_counter=0;    
        }
      }
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
  ovf_counter++;
  TCNT0 = 0;
}
```

i dont know what is wrong.

If i check in the **while(1)** loop the status of the counter register TCNT0 it works. So the counter is overflowing as it should, but it never enters on a overflow event the **ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)** function.

Comment: Too little RAM to use interrupts in C. Post what avr-size shows on your elf. Especially the data and bss sections.

Comment: Are you linking in the crttn10.o startup file?

Comment: Are you sure you waited long enough? This looks like it would take about 67 seconds to overflow.  
https://www.google.com/search?q=1%2F(+((1Mhz)+%2F1024)+%2F+65536+)&oq=1%2F(+((1Mhz)+%2F1024)+%2F+65536+)&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.32319j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I'm not an AVR guy, but I suspect you need to globally enable interrupts --https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-newbies-guide-avr-interrupts?page=all

Comment: @ScottSeidman the `sei();` call does that.

Comment: I added now the size in my comment. I changed my prescaler. I use sei() for enabling globally the interrupts. LED not working.

Comment: Oops, missed it.  I was looking specifically for it, and didn't see it!

Comment: anyone an other idea why its not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake.
I used:

```
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){. . .}
```

instead of

```
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect){. . .}
```

Now it works! At the overflow of timer0 the interrupt routine will be executed.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It may look similar, but **ATtiny45 Timer/Counter0 is 8-bit** (it needs to count to 256 + 1 for overflow) , so for example waiting for overflow interrupt when CLK=1MHz, prescaler 1024 will take about 0.26 sec.
 **ATtiny10 Timer/Counter0 is 16-bit** (counts to 65536). For same settings as above (1MHz clock, prescaler 1024) it gives 256 times 0.26sec = almost 67 seconds to overflow (as mentioned by bigjosh).

Comment: Hi, i changed now the prescaler to have clk/8 with the line TCCR0B = (1 << CS01); So i will have an overflow every 0.524seconds. But i can't see the LED blinking.